# Coupon problem from Ross' Probability Models

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, coupon-collector

This is a question from Sheldon M Ross' Intro to Probability Models.

> Suppose that each coupon obtained is, independent of what has been previously
>   obtained, equally likely to be any of $m$ different types. Find the expected number of coupons one needs to obtain in order to have at least one of each type.
>
> Hint: Let $X$ be the number needed. It is useful to represent $X$ by
>   $X = \sum_{i=1}{X_i}$ where each $X_i$ is a geometric random variable.

I did it using this hint and I now get $m^2$ as $E[X]$. I'm not sure if this is right and more importantly, I'm not able to understand why/how it can be modeled as the sum of many geometric distributions.

My initial approach was to define the indicator random variable

$$X_i = \begin{cases} 
      1 & \textrm{if ith coupon is new}  \\   
      0 & \textrm{otherwise} 
   \end{cases}
$$

and then take $X = \sum_{i=1}{X_i}$ but I'm not sure how to proceed with that.

Comment: Hint: Let $X_i$ be the time to get the $i^{\text{th}}$ new coupon after you have obtained $i - 1$ different kinds.

Comment: Oh. But do I then consider time in some discrete steps? 

Also, is $m^2^ the right answer?

Comment: Yes you will have to consider time in discrete steps. And the answer is $m \log m$.